# Swift - Edit PDF QuickLook

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I would like to edit a PDF and save it in an IOS app.
Is it possible to do this with the [QuickLookController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/qlpreviewcontroller)?

Does any one know how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Apple's QuickLook Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook) documentation does mention that

> A QLPreviewController object, or Quick Look preview controller,
>   provides a specialized view for previewing an item.

So, I believe it is a framework meant only for previewing documents. The [functions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/quicklook_functions) listed do not **edit** PDF data.

Here are some third-party libraries/frameworks that you may find useful.

- [pdftron](https://www.pdftron.com/pdf-sdk/ios/)
- [pspdfkit](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/features/document-editor/)
- [LazyPDFKit](https://github.com/lazyprogram/LazyPDFKit) (This is no longer maintained by the developer, hence may be outdated)

Another [page](http://ipdfdev.com/2013/03/13/pdf-frameworks-and-tools-for-ios-and-mac-os-x/) that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I used to custom PDF trough iOS App, and I advise you to use PDFKit.
It's easy and fast to use it!

With PDFKit you can edit a PDF and save it in an IOS app with HTML/CSS!